# Dockerfile Entrypoint seems to append instead of overwrite

Tags: docker

I want to overwrite the entrypoint in dockerfile, but the result shows that the finnal entrypoint is the base image's entrypoint append my entrypoint. 
Here is my Docker file.

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
ENTRYPOINT echo 1
CMD 2
```

After build this image by `docker build -t test .`
, I run a container by `docker run test 3`.

As I suppose, the finally command which is executed is `echo 1 2 3`, and the result should be `1 2 3`.

However, the result is '1'.

I query the actual command using `docker inspect -f "{{.Name}} {{.Path}} {{.Args}}" $(docker ps -a -q)` and I get following result.
`/adoring_chaum /bin/sh [-c echo 1 2]`

It's seems that the actual command is the old entrypoint with the new entrypoint as the parameter.And the CMD in dockerfile and runtime parameter is ignored.

I can not find any explanation from docker document.

Could any one give me an explanation?

Answer (score 3):

Remember that there are two forms of `ENTRYPOINT`, `CMD`, and `RUN`.  You can "spell" these commands like a bare string, or like a JSON array.  If you use a bare string, Docker implicitly wraps whatever you put there in `/bin/sh -c '...'`.

There is a table in the Dockerfile documentation describing [Understand how CMD and ENTRYPOINT interact](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact).  According to that table, if `ENTRYPOINT` is a bare string, `CMD` is always ignored.

(This isn't 100% technically accurate, but the more accurate answer depends on understanding arcane details of how `sh -c` actually works.)

This will do what you want if you use the JSON-array form instead, to avoid the implicit `sh -c` wrapper

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/echo", "1"]
CMD ["2"]
```

The pattern I generally find useful is to reserve `ENTRYPOINT` for a wrapper script that does some first-time setup, and then `exec "$@"` to run the `CMD`.  A typical `docker run` command has so many arguments that being able to leave off the command word for an interactive tool packaged in Docker isn't much benefit.  If you prefer exclusive `CMD` then it's much easier to run a debugging shell, possibly with your first-time setup done if you're using an `ENTRYPOINT` wraper.

```
CMD ["/bin/echo", "1", "2"]
```

Answer (score 2):

To overwrite ENTRYPOINT, you should use --entrypoint option. Whatever arguments passed after the image name will be the arguments(overwrites CMD) for the existing command specified as ENTRYPOINT in Dockerfile.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But I also want to overwrite the entrypoint in dockerfile because I don't want to expose the entrypoint to the user who run the container.